# ThreadPoolExecutor Utility methods

Tags: java, multithreading, threadpool

I am writing a thread pool utility in my `multithreading` program. i just need to validate the following methods are correct and are they return the right values for me. i am using a `LinkedBlockingQueue` with size of 1. and also I refer to the java doc and it always says 'method will return **approximate**' number phrase. so i doubt weather following conditions are correct.

```
public boolean isPoolIdle() {
    return myThreadPool.getActiveCount() == 0;
}

public int getAcceptableTaskCount() {
    //initially poolSize is 0 ( after pool executes something it started to change )
    if (myThreadPool.getPoolSize() == 0) {
        return myThreadPool.getCorePoolSize() - myThreadPool.getActiveCount();
    }
    return myThreadPool.getPoolSize() - myThreadPool.getActiveCount();
}

public boolean isPoolReadyToAcceptTasks(){
    return myThreadPool.getActiveCount()<myThreadPool.getCorePoolSize();
}
```

Please let me know your thoughts and suggestions.

UPDATE

interesting thing was if pool returns me there are 3 threads available from the `getAcceptableTaskCount` method and when i pass 3 tasks to the pool some times one task got rejected and it is handle by `RejectedExecutionHandler`. some times pool will handle all the tasks i passed. i am wondering why pool is rejected the tasks since i am passing tasks according to the available thread count.

--------- implementation of the answer of gray---

```
class MyTask implements Runnable {

@Override
public void run() {
    try {
        Thread.sleep(1000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    System.out.println("exec");
}
```

}

```
@Test
public void testTPool(){

    ExecutorService pool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5);

    List<Future<MyTask>> list = new ArrayList<Future<MyTask>>();

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        MyTask t = new MyTask();
        list.add(pool.submit(t, t));
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {

        Future<MyTask> t = list.get(i);

        System.out.println("Result -"+t.isDone());

        MyTask m = new MyTask();

        list.add(pool.submit(m,m));
    }
}
```

This will print `Result -false` in the console meaning that task is not complete.

Comment: Can you explain _why_ you want to get this information?  As the documentation states, there are race conditions around getting those statistics so your methods are going to be subject to them as well.  They will be returning approximations.

Comment: @Gray - fist i want to do some file processing in my application. for that i scheduled a job. so once job is wake up and try to send tasks to the pool ,i need to know that if pool is idle or pool can accept the tasks. if pool can accept, i need to know how much free threads in the pool. if it is 5 i will send 5 tasks to the pool to do the processing.

Comment: You would be better off limiting the tasks rather than the threads. Trying to micro-manage threads, or thread pools, is difficult and error/disaster-prone. Typically, I throttle such designs by object pooling.  If I create 16 tasks at startup, store them on a producer-consumer 'pool queue' and arrange that every thread that wants to issue a task to the threadpool has to get one from the poolQueue, that limits the number of tasks running at any one time to 16 without dodgy 'getState' threadpool calls.  The threadpool can requeue the tasks, when done, so that they can be recycled.

Comment: @MartinJames - Thanks for the explanation.i am taking tasks from a vector. it will update and sort frequently. so i prioritize the first set of tasks that are in the vector and ignore other tasks.like lets say pool can accept 5 tasks. so i get the first most 5 tasks from the vector and assign them to the pool.ignore the other tasks in the vector since they may be update / remove from a separate cycle.so when the next cycle checks lets say thread pool can accept 10 tasks i get the first most 10 from the vector and give it to the pool. for do that i think i need above methods.am i doing right?

Answer (score 0):

From your comments:

> i need to know that if pool is idle or pool can accept the tasks. if pool can accept, i need to know how much free threads in the pool. if it is 5 i will send 5 tasks to the pool to do the processing.

I don't think that you should be doing the pool accounting yourself.  For your thread pool if you use `Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5)` then you can submit as many tasks as you want and it will only run them in 5 threads.

> so i get the first most 5 tasks from the vector and assign them to the pool.ignore the other tasks in the vector since they may be update / remove from a separate cycle

Ok, I see.  So you want to maximize parallelization while at the same time not pre-loading jobs?  I would think that something like the following pseudo code would work:

```
  int numThreads = 5;
  ExecutorService threadPool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(numThreads);
  List<Future<MyJob>> futures = new ArrayList<Future<MyJob>>();
  // submit the initial jobs
  for (int i = 0; i < numThreads; i++) {
      MyJob myJob = getNextBestJob();
      futures.add(threadPool.submit(myJob, myJob));
  }
  // the list is growing so we use for i
  for (int i = 0; i < futures.size(); i++) {
      // wait for a job to finish
      MyJob myJob = futures.get(i);
      // process the job somehow
      // get the next best job now that the previous one finished
      MyJob nextJob = getNextBestJob();
      if (nextJob != null) {
         // submit the next job unless we are done
         futures.add(threadPool.submit(myJob, myJob));
      }
  }
```

However, I don't quite understand how the thread count would change however.  If you edit your question with some more details I can tweak my response.

Comment: hi @gray - thanks a lot for ur answer. i just looked in to the `QueuedThreadPool' and there is a method called `getIdleThreads()` i am looking for that and i dnt have a proper idea of the consequences. thanks for your turn over..

Comment: i have tried your algorithm and it seems like it will lead to a deadlock situation. i will post the java code that i used to implement it.